# net/url package: strip query from url

Tags: go

I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something on the net/url package. Is there a way to get the url without the query, without using using the strings package to strip it out?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, _ := url.Parse("/url?foo=bar&foo=baz")
    fmt.Printf("full uri: %#v\n", u.String())
    fmt.Printf("query: %#v", u.Query())
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/injlx_ElAp

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this question would be clearer if you gave an example since the code you posted, although url-related, doesn't look to be doing anything like "getting the url without the query using the strings package to strip it out".

Comment: As I suspected I missed it. Parse() places what I needed in URL.Path

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure if this is  what you are asking but you can use the `u.Path` attribute to get the path of the url or any of the attributes specified by URL

```
type URL struct {
    Scheme   string
    Opaque   string    // encoded opaque data
    User     *Userinfo // username and password information
    Host     string    // host or host:port
    Path     string
    RawQuery string // encoded query values, without '?'
    Fragment string // fragment for references, without '#'
}
// scheme://[userinfo@]host/path[?query][#fragment]
```

Example:

```
 package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, _ := url.Parse("http://www.test.com/url?foo=bar&foo=baz#this_is_fragment")
    fmt.Println("full uri:", u.String())
    fmt.Println("scheme:", u.Scheme)
    fmt.Println("opaque:", u.Opaque)
    fmt.Println("Host:", u.Host)
    fmt.Println("Path", u.Path)
    fmt.Println("Fragment", u.Fragment)
    fmt.Println("RawQuery", u.RawQuery)
    fmt.Printf("query: %#v", u.Query())
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/mijE73rUgw

Answer (score 7):

Yes. In case you need to get url without the query part (and without fragment/anchor) you can simply overwrite them, set to an empty string:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    u, _ := url.Parse("/url?foo=bar&foo=baz")
    fmt.Printf("full uri: %#v\n", u.String())
    fmt.Printf("query: %#v", u.Query())

    u.RawQuery = ""
    u.Fragment = ""

    fmt.Println("result url:", u.String())
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/RY4vlfjj3_5

In comparison to using only `u.Host + u.Path` or `u.Path` in this case you will keep the rest of the url: protocol, username and password, host.

Comment: Is not removing the ? if it ends on one.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can! The [URL type](http://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL) is defined this way:

```
type URL struct {
    Scheme   string
    Opaque   string    // encoded opaque data
    User     *Userinfo // username and password information
    Host     string    // host or host:port
    Path     string
    RawQuery string // encoded query values, without '?'
    Fragment string // fragment for references, without '#'
}
// scheme://[userinfo@]host/path[?query][#fragment]
```

So you can use:

```
u, _ := url.Parse()
result := u.Host + u.Path
```